# Netty-4.0.0.CR6 throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, netty, out-of-memory

I am trying my application with latest build of Netty-4 CR6. At the server end of my application, I get the following error at a load of around 200 requests / sec:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:393)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.messageReceived(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeMessageReceived(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireMessageReceived(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:364)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireMessageReceived(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:347)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireMessageReceived(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:780)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:489)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:464)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventL
```

It is a file transfer application. I am using client and server build with Netty-4 CR6 jar. In every request the client creates a WebSocket connection, transfer a file of around 850KB and finally closes the connection by sending CloseWebSocketFrame.

Comment: Hello, as i am getting this exception at server end , these many requests are not being processed. Almost half of total hits have been failed.

Comment: Perhaps you should increase the maximum direct memory using `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` option?  More detailed steps for reproduction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [bug](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1393). You could have run into it. The options here are
1. Use `msgs.releaseAll()` in your upstream handler.
2. Use `io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler` class as your consuming handler. Then you dont need to use the `releaseAll` logic since its taken care for you internally by netty.

Comment: Hello, I tried the same scenario with Jetty-8 Websocket APIs and it works for me :)

Comment: @Trustin Yes I supplied that JVM option and put the value to 256 M but I was getting the same problem.